# Combining LAST and Cumulative SUM on influxdb subquery data

Tags: influxdb

I have some telemetry data that looks like this:

```
> select * from connected_users LIMIT 100
name: connected_users
time                event_id value
----                -------- -----
1605485019101319658 13759    2
1605485299566004832 13759    0
1605490011182967926 13760    4
1605490171409428188 13760    0
1605490207031398071 13760    7
1605490246151204709 13760    0
1605491054403726308 13761    1
1605491403050521520 13761    0
1605491433407347399 13762    2
1605491527773331816 13762    3
1605492020976088377 12884    1
1605492219827002782 13761    1
1605492613984911844 13763    1
1605492806683323942 13763    0
...
```

These writes only occur when something changes on the event (i.e. are not at fixed intervals).  I want to write a query which will give me a cumulative sum per-minute of the current "value" on all the event_ids.  However, because I can't guarantee that a new data value will have been written in the preceding 60 seconds, I use `LAST` to get whatever was last set per `event_id`

So far I got to:

```
SELECT SUM(*) FROM 
    (SELECT LAST("value") FROM 
        "connected_users" WHERE 
        time <= now() AND 
        time >= now() - 3h 
        GROUP BY time(1m), "event_id" fill(previous))
GROUP BY time(1m)
```

But this seems to give me a much lower outer "value" than expected, and a lot of duplicate time entries (and thus a lot of duplicate entries in the output data.)

I can see that the inner query is correct, because If I just run that in isolation, I can stack the output data in Grafana and manually see the correct total value in the graph.  However, I want to have a single series rather than a grouped set of series, and I can't wrap my head around how to transform the data to do that.

EDIT: To give more context:

This is the inner query (Grafana, hence `$timeFilter`):

`SELECT last("value") FROM "connected_users" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1m), "event_id" fill(previous)`

This produces a chart which I can stack and is correct:

[image: Chart 1 - All series stacked in Grafana]

If I then wrap that inner query in a `SUM` and `GROUP BY time(1m)` again, I can isolate a single series:

`SELECT SUM(*) FROM (SELECT last("value") FROM "connected_users" WHERE $timeFilter AND ("event_id = '9970') GROUP BY time(1m), "event_id" fill(previous)) GROUP BY time(1m)`

[image: Chart 2 - Single Series with SUM applied]

However, If I remove the `AND` and attempt to `SUM` all series values, I just end up with both a jumbled mess (presumably because there are duplicate/overlapping `time` values?) and also a lower max value than expected (expecting 18, got 8):

`SELECT SUM(*) FROM (SELECT last("value") FROM "connected_users" WHERE $timeFilter GROUP BY time(1m), "event_id" fill(previous)) GROUP BY time(1m)`

[image: Chart 3 - A mess...]

Comment: How it looks like when you select only one serverId in the inner query?

Comment: Too much text to add here, so I've updated the original question with what happens in that scenario :)

Comment: Last graph is overall graph, but label is configure per tag event_id. I would also try to SUM("last") explicitly. Check query inspector, that mess in the graph can be because mess in the input data - or directly verify queries/result in the InfluxDB.